# I keep getting reputation points for an answer to a CW question

Tags: support, reputation

I keep getting reputation points for [an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/219633/41291) to the question [Most intriguing mathematical epigraphs](https://mathoverflow.net/q/219534/41291) which has been made community wiki some days ago.

[image]

Not that I don't like it but...

Comment: I just upvoted your answer, but it doesn't seem to have had an effect on your point score.

Comment: @StefanKohl But it did! I'm adding a snapshot, the last entry must be yours

Comment: "I keep getting reputation points for an answer to a CW question" - This could lead to a CW complex!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not get any reputation from this answer (beyond the one you got before it was CW). Only *the event* that the post was upvoted is recorded there, yet no change in points is recorded. 
Note the lack of a small green number next to the line, which is present for "Exponentiating vector spaces."

Further, note that your daily reputation gain, the larger 20 in green, is only 20 points, even though you got 4 upvotes on a questions and 3 on an answer, which usually would give 50. (Yet the answers did not give anything, as they should.)

Comment: I see. I should be more attentive, sorry for the noise

Comment: You are welcome. It is not completely intuitive that all voting event are recorded under the tab "reputation," so I can see where the confusion comes from.

Comment: The same thing happens when you receive upvotes (on non-CW posts) but you have already hit the daily reputation cap of 200: the votes show up on your reputation page, but no points are displayed beside them.